# Android: how to display notification text

Tags: android, push-notification

I tried to display notification by this

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.front2).setContentTitle("WAKE ME UP!").setContentText(text);


        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

BUT, currently, it's not show the text like other apps ( i mean: diplay text line by line on notifycation bar), my code is just display the icon con notifycation bar.
If i want to see message, i have to open the notifycation dropdown.

Question: How can i do a notification like other apps

Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it can help you:

```
mBuilder.setTicker("some text");
```

Answer (score 1):

try this it will work 
mBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert, Click Me!");
mBuilder.setContentText("Hi, This is Android Notification Detail!");